# Adding Cell Formating in Excel in c#

Tags: c#, webforms, export-to-excel

I have exported html contents into excel using below code.

```
 protected void ExportToExcelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportedHtml.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        Response.Write(ExportDiv.InnerHtml);
        Response.End();

    }
```

excel sheet is below

[image: Below is excel sheet]

Now I need to do excel cell format for the cells date, id  using c#

How to do excel cell format using c#

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to use ClosedXML. Well-described documentation, a large community. I myself have worked quite a lot with this library. I recommend it.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML).